Responding security mechanism not supported , is it due to some config issues in standalone?
This is my standalone.xml:-
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:6.0">
            <datasources>
              <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/sample" pool-name="sample" enabled="true" spy="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:db2://myDatabaseURL:60000/sample</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>db2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>admin123</user-name>
                        <password>admin1234</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>600</query-timeout>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>       
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="db2" module="com.ibm.db2">
                        <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>

now in mine the structure is modules->com->ibm->db2->main->db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar, module.xml:
error I am getting is security mechanism not supported ---what could be the issue??
